# How do I hide a local task (tab) if a module is disabled?

Tags: 8, routes

I would like my local tasks (tabs), defined in *mymodule.links.task.yml*, to appear only if a certain module is enabled. If a certain module is disabled, I want the tab to be hidden.

```
mymodule.alpha:
  route_name: mymodule.alpha
  base_route: mymodule.alpha
  title: 'Alpha'

mymodule.bravo:
  route_name: mymodule.bravo
  base_route: mymodule.alpha
  title: 'Bravo'
```

My understanding is that this can be acheived by adding a *_module_dependencies* key to my *routing.yml* file.

> _module_dependencies: Optionally use this key to specify one or more modules that are required to serve this path. You can combine module names with a + (plus) for an AND relationship or , (comma) for an OR relationship. For example, _module_dependencies: 'node + search' means both node and search are needed, _module_dependencies: 'node, search' means either node or search are needed. If your module already depends on other modules for its behavior (via info.yml dependencies), there is, of course, no need for specifying the dependency here as well; however, for optional dependencies, where routes are provided only if those optional dependent modules are also enabled, this is a useful option.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

```
mymodule.alpha:
  path: '/admin/reports/mymodule/alpha'
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\mymodule\Controller\AlphaController::render
    _title: 'Alpha'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access site reports'
    _module_dependencies: 'comment' # this is module is enabled, this line does not cause a white screen on cache rebuild

mymodule.bravo:
  path: '/admin/reports/mymodule/bravo'
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\mymodule\Controller\BravoController::render
    _title: 'Bravo'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access site reports'
    _module_dependencies: 'statistics' # this is module is disabled, this line does cause a white screen on cache rebuild
```

However, if a module is disabled, I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "mymodule.bravo" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 187 of /var/www/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

The error is thrown even when I visit: */admin/reports/mymodule/alpha*.

Comment: This is a head scratcher, Did you clear the cache? Looks like you might have to use `_custom_access:` and do the module check logic in here...

Comment: When developing, *always* enable verbose error logging, then you will get an error with the actual problem instead of useless wsod. One reason for that could be that the controller extends or uses something that statistics.module provides, AFAIK the controller class is still loaded, as the route still exists, it will just deny access at runtime. The safest option is to define the route dynamically.

Comment: To add to @Berdir comment, You can enable verbose error logging by adding `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to your development environment **settings.php** file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe my problem was that if the module was disabled then the route would not exist - and this would have my *links.task.yml* trying to create a local task from a non existent route.

My solution was to [generate a dynamic local task](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks) instead, so that the local task is only created, if the module is enabled:

*mymodule.links.task.yml*

```
mymodule.bravo:
  deriver: 'Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Derivative\BravoLocalTasks'
```

*src/Plugin/Derivative/BravoLocalTasks.php*

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Derivative;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase;

/**
 * Generates local tasks.
 */
class BravoLocalTasks extends DeriverBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
    if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('statistics')) {
      $this->derivatives['mymodule.bravo'] = $base_plugin_definition;
      $this->derivatives['mymodule.bravo']['route_name'] = 'mymodule.bravo';
      $this->derivatives['mymodule.bravo']['base_route'] = 'mymodule.alpha';
      $this->derivatives['mymodule.bravo']['title'] = 'Bravo';
    }
    return $this->derivatives;
  }
}
```

I believe I will have to create a distinct class for every route that requires dynamic local tasks.

If you have a better solution, please post.